# In nodejs, when the method is called multiple times at the same time, is the variable is shared

Tags: node.js

I want to generate the short id of number type, but when I call shortid method and output id and emaill, the contents of the output in the console are the same as the incoming variable. [the gist in github](https://gist.github.com/3b417ac76c0ffad0f74c1adc10c6c846.git)

Comment: You should always post code here in case links die.

Comment: Sorry about it, stackoverflow must make me add more detail for code, so I add code in github gist.

Answer (score 0):

I get an answer that  change 'var self = this ' to 'var self = {}', because 'this' in method equal 'global'.